# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in firefox using simplewebrtc

Tags: jquery, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am trying to use simple-webRTC to stream video and audio from a client to node.js. I am working on HTTPS but i have this error, the problem is this script:
...
    
...
and the error is:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sandbox.simplewebrtc.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1586679392650-5. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

When i remove that i i have no stream and get this error:
ReferenceError: SimpleWebRTC is not defined.

I've been looking for 5 days but I haven't found anything that works. I don't know what should i do. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

...

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     // Chat platform
  const chatTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#chat-template').html());
  const chatContentTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#chat-content-template').html());
  const chatEl = $('#chat');
  const formEl = $('.form');
  const messages = [];
  let username;

  // Local Video`enter code here`
  const localImageEl = $('#local-image');
  const localVideoEl = $('#local-video');

  // Remote Videos
  const remoteVideoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#remote-video-template').html());
  const remoteVideosEl = $('#remote-videos');
  let remoteVideosCount = 0;

  // Hide cameras until they are initialized
  localVideoEl.hide();

  // Add validation rules to Create/Join Room Form
  formEl.form({
    fields: {
      roomName: 'empty',
      username: 'empty',
    },
  });

  // create our webrtc connection
  const webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
    localVideoEl: 'local-video',
    // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
    remoteVideosEl: 'remote-videos',
    // immediately ask for camera access
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    debug: false,
    detectSpeakingEvents: true,
    autoAdjustMic: false,
  });

  // We got access to local camera
  webrtc.on('localStream', () => {
    localImageEl.hide();
    localVideoEl.show();
  });

  // Remote video was added
  webrtc.on('videoAdded', (video, peer) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    const id = webrtc.getDomId(peer);
    const html = remoteVideoTemplate({ id });
    if (remoteVideosCount === 0) {
      remoteVideosEl.html(html);
    } else {
      remoteVideosEl.append(html);
    }
    $(`#${id}`).html(video);
    $(`#${id} video`).addClass('ui image medium'); // Make video element responsive
    remoteVideosCount += 1;
  });

  // Update Chat Messages
  const updateChatMessages = () => {
    const html = chatContentTemplate({ messages });
    const chatContentEl = $('#chat-content');
    chatContentEl.html(html);
    // automatically scroll downwards
    const scrollHeight = chatContentEl.prop('scrollHeight');
    chatContentEl.animate({ scrollTop: scrollHeight }, 'slow');
  };

  // Post Local Message
  const postMessage = (message) => {
    const chatMessage = {
      username,
      message,
      postedOn: new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB'),
    };
    // Send to all peers
    webrtc.sendToAll('chat', chatMessage);
    // Update messages locally
    messages.push(chatMessage);
    $('#post-message').val('');
    updateChatMessages();
  };

  // Display Chat Interface
  const showChatRoom = (room) => {
    formEl.hide();
    const html = chatTemplate({ room });
    chatEl.html(html);
    const postForm = $('form');
    postForm.form({
      message: 'empty',
    });
    $('#post-btn').on('click', () => {
      const message = $('#post-message').val();
      postMessage(message);
    });
    $('#post-message').on('keyup', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const message = $('#post-message').val();
        postMessage(message);
      }
    });
  };

  // Register new Chat Room
  const createRoom = (roomName) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.info(`Creating new room: ${roomName}`);
    webrtc.createRoom(roomName, (err, name) => {
      formEl.form('clear');
      showChatRoom(name);
      postMessage(`${username} created chatroom`);
    });
  };

  // Join existing Chat Room
  const joinRoom = (roomName) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`Joining Room: ${roomName}`);
    webrtc.joinRoom(roomName);
    showChatRoom(roomName);
    postMessage(`${username} joined chatroom`);
  };

  // Receive message from remote user
  webrtc.connection.on('message', (data) => {
    if (data.type === 'chat') {
      const message = data.payload;
      messages.push(message);
      updateChatMessages();
    }
  });

  // Room Submit Button Handler
  $('.submit').on('click', (event) => {
    if (!formEl.form('is valid')) {
      return false;
    }
    username = $('#username').val();
    const roomName = $('#roomName').val().toLowerCase();
    if (event.target.id === 'create-btn') {
      createRoom(roomName);
    } else {
      joinRoom(roomName);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

...

Comment: there is nothing in url

Comment: can you show code where you call http request call?

Comment: @Serdar I edited my question, please check it again.

Comment: I cannot open  the link you provided. I am using macbook. Can you paste just small portion of code where you have problem. I need to see how you make http call?

Comment: and by the way webrtc is not intented for client to server communication. it is intended for browser to browser communication bypassing server. server is used only for signaling to make initial connection set up.

Comment: @Serdar I added the code. Recheck please.